# How to execute a batch file with pascal?

Tags: pascal

How can I execute a batch file with pascal ?

I try this, but it doesn't work :

```
Program Program_;
uses dos;
begin
 exec('C:\Users\Vincenzo\Desktop\FILE BATCH.bat','');
 readln;
end.
```

What do I have to do ?

Comment: You probably need to run `cmd.exe` passing the batch file as a parameter.

Comment: `exec('cmd.exe', '/C "C:\Users\Vincenzo\Desktop\FILE BATCH.bat"');`

Comment: I try  [ exec('cmd.exe', '/C "C:\Users\Vincenzo\Desktop\FILE BATCH.bat"'); ]

Comment: I try [exec('cmd.exe', ':\Users\Vincenzo\Desktop\FILE BATCH.bat');

Comment: I try [ exec('C:\Users\Vincenzo\Desktop\FILE BATCH.bat', 'cmd.exe'); ]

Comment: But they aren' t correct ! They don't work !!

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments, edit your question. And "*they don't work*" is not an acceptable error description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**TLama was right! !! The command is :**

```
[Code]

exec('cmd.exe', '/C "C:\Users\Vincenzo\Desktop\FILE BATCH.bat"');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the *Shell* command:
http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/unix/shell.html

For example:

```
program batchfileexec;
uses Unix;
begin
   Shell('yourbatchfilename');
end.
```

Just type your file's name in the *Shell* command.

Comment: Please us fpsystem now, shell is deprecated since 2003, and has been removed in recent versions (2.6+ or 3.0+ ).